# Touch pad mouse stopped working often in Windows 11

Tags: windows, bios, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Touch pad mouse stopped working suddenly often for Windows 11 on Dell Inspiron 2 in 1.

Tried all things suggested on internet. Driver latest.

The solution: I have to reboot computer and go to BIOS settings:

```
 Reset BIOS to default.
```

Is there any software that could have changed BIOS settings?

Comment: Run a full set of Dell Hardware Diagnostics. It may be necessary to replace the keyboard.